# How do i get the four next items of uneven array and then wrapping around? (array carousel with a set range selection)

Tags: javascript, arrays, modulo

I have an array of 13 items, and i want to display four of them at a time. The first time it should be [0, 1, 2, 3], the next refresh should render [4, 5, 6, 7]. After [8, 9, 10, 11] it should display [12, 0, 1, 2]. Basically i want the four items in a subarray

And i want to be able to keep cycling through this array, and always get the subsequent 4 items. I have a problem with the wrapping-around part! I found it very hard "resetting" at zero but having the remainder added to the next remaining elements, if that makes sense.

I have tried with the % operator and getting the remainder. But honestly i am very lost here! I would appreciate help with a solution with js or similar.

edit: tried with @Bamars help:

```js
 const [offSetIndex, setOffSetIndex] = useState<number>(0);  
  
  const handleRefreshMeals = () => {
    const end = (offSetIndex + 4) % meals.length;
    let result = []

    if(end < offSetIndex) {
      result = meals.slice(offSetIndex).concat(meals.slice(0, end))
    } else {
      result = meals.slice(offSetIndex, offSetIndex + 4);
    }

    setOffSetIndex(offSetIndex + 4)
    setCurrentMeals(result)
  };
```

But i am clearly doing something wrong

Comment: Use `end = (start + 4) % array.length`. When `end < start`, it's wrapping around, and you'll need to use two slices to get the part you want: `array.slice(start)` concatenated with `array.slice(0, end)`

Comment: @Barmar added an edit to the post, tried with your tips but i think i am implementing it wrong! again appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not wrapping around when you save the updated index. Replace

```
setOffSetIndex(offSetIndex + 4)
```

with

```
setOffSetIndex(end)
```